# Kubuntu 15.04 desktop freezes after short time

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, freeze

**BACKGROUND:**

I am a new Kubuntu user and I have installed Kubuntu 15.04 on my system for the first time.  The installation completed without error and I can boot into a working system.

Here are my system details:

[image: My System Details]

**THE PROBLEM:**

After a short time of use, the desktop freezes.  The desktop context menu no longer appears when I right-select with the mouse, and the toolbar at the bottom of the screen no longer responds.  The time display, which is in the bottom right corner of the bottom toolbar, freezes as well.

In the frozen condition, the rest of the system continues to function normally.  I can use any applications which are open and I can launch new applications from the terminal or from within other applications.  I have a custom keyboard shortcut to launch a new terminal and this continues to work as well.

If I allow the desktop to time-out due inactivity, it correctly returns to the login splash screen.  The splash screen shows the time and it is updated *from* the time that the desktop originally froze *to* the time that the splash screen appeared, but it does not update any further and I cannot log in because the login screen does not respond to mouse or keyboard interaction.

**MY QUESTION:**

I have researched this issue and found a number of references to plasma 5 freezing.  However, I cannot find any resolution.  Some people suggested that running dmesg may give some clues as to the cause of the problem.  Here is a copy of my dmesg output after the freeze has happened:

[dmesg output](http://brianhoskins.uk/files/public-docs/forum-images2/konsole_output_dmesg_plasma5_freezing.txt)

Can some one with more Kubuntu experience point me in the right direction? If not an answer, then perhaps a line of diagnosis to follow?

Comment: Having tried a number of different options I eventually decided to attempt a fresh install.  The fresh install is now working without the freezing problem, and I am slowly re-tracing my steps, installing all my basic software one thing at a time, and taking timeshift backups at each point.

Comment: Hi Brian, I was wondering if you every found out the cause of this freeze problem. I'm experiencing the exact same symptoms, but a fresh install seems rather invasive. I'm still hoping for a quick fix... :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find any quick fix, but the problem did not return after I reinstalled. I am sure there would be a better solution than to reinstall but unfortunately I am not competent enough with Linux yet to figure it out on my own and I wasn't able to attract any responses to my plea for help here. Best of luck! Please post back if you find anything!